# pub build fail with "segmentation fault (core dumped)" on EC2 small intance

Tags: amazon-ec2, dart, ubuntu-14.04, dart-pub

Am trying to automate the deployment of my Dart web application, but i keep getting the "segmentation fault (core dumped)" whenever i run pub build on my EC2's Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS small instance using Dart 1.9.X
You can reproduce this using the example project from my repo : https://github.com/youssefgh/angular-dart-google-maps

Comment: I  guess you should create a bug report at http://dartbug.com

Comment: Can you give some more details as I cannot reproduce? I just created a new EC2 t2.small instance with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and installed Dart 1.9.3 as described on https://www.dartlang.org/downloads/linux.html. Then I installed git, cloned your project, added `/usr/lib/dart/bin` to the path and ran `pub build` in the examples directory of your project without seeing any crashes.

Comment: Thanks for trying, i suspect there is something wrong with my instance. I'll try to delete it and recreate another one and see if the error still persist

Comment: I just did the same but i still get the error :/ and pub build -v can't help. what kind of details i need to provide ?